# Reported EPS for Lowe's Companies Inc

Tags: stocks, earnings-per-share

I know that the EPS estimate today for Lowe's Companies Inc is estimated at 3.1$ per share while the reported EPS is 2.73$ per share in November last year.

[image]

We don't know the reported EPS today yet, but the price has increased a lot since the opening this morning. Is it normal? Is it because we expected the reported EPS to be higher than the reported EPS from November last year?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We don't know the reported EPS today yet...

In this case, we do, it's 3.27, they announced before market opened.

From Google:
[image]

Here's a handy site that keeps an earnings calendar, you can toggle between BMO (before market opens) and AMC (after market closes) for each day: https://earningswhispers.com/calendar

There are instances where earnings have been leaked early, and some stocks move based on the earning results of other similar companies before their own results are announced, but in this case just a standard BMO earnings release.

Answer (score 1):

The stock was *already* expected to have a higher EPS this year (3.10) than last year (2.73), so if anything it's likely that the market thinks it will have a higher EPS than the previously expected 3.10.

Note that EPS is only one of many metrics that affect stock price. You can't attribute the jump to just one metric in a vacuum. It's *possible* that a higher rumored EPS caused some buying, but there's no way to know for certain.